# PAC Learning for OLS and noisy regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, references, pac-learning

Hi guys I would like to get some references on PAC Learning for the following settings:

1. PAC Learning type results for OLS. Most materials that tackle OLS are from a statistical point of view, i.e. assume $y=w^\top x+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is Gaussian. In this regime, we can talk about parameter estimation error and in-sample/out-of-sample estimation error. In the PAC setting, there are many results that give uniform convergence for all linear functions $w$, but what about results specifically for OLS? For example, algorithmic stability approach looks at algorithms particularly, but I believe it only works for regularized OLS because it's strongly-convex.
2. What if I want to get a PAC bound on linear regression where the data has noise? Say we observe $x+\epsilon$. Most results I found are for classification with Massart noise. What if I want to look at regression? The issue here is the training data and test data have different (but only slightly shifted) distribution.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Rui Castro's class notes:
https://www.win.tue.nl/~rmcastro/2DI70/files/2DI70_Lecture_Notes.pdf
or Rob Nowak's lecture notes:
https://nowak.ece.wisc.edu/SLT09.html